# Is it possible to remove touch messages (WM_POINTERDOWN etc.) that an application receives?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, touch, setwindowshookex

I have successfully installed a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook with `SetWindowsHookEx` and I can see the `WM_POINTERDOWN`, `WM_POINTERUP` etc. messages that the application receives. (It is a 32 bit desktop application running on Windows 8.1.)

Now, I not only want to *see* those messages, but I want to *remove* some of them.

The documententation for [GetMsgProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The GetMsgProc hook procedure can examine or **modify** the message. After the hook procedure     returns control to the system, the GetMessage or PeekMessage function returns the message, along with any modifications, to the application that originally called it.

With `WM_KEYUP` messages this seem to work fine. I can set the message to `WM_NULL` in the hook, and the key event will disappear.

With `WM_POINTER...` messages however, this does not seem to work. The application still receives the messages (validated in the debugger).

Maybe there is some other way to filter/remove such messages?

Edit: It has to work with unmodified third-party applications (hence the usage of a hook).

Update: I managed to prevent click events from touch by aggressively calling `PeekMessage` within the hook (probably not a good idea in the long term). However, I still can't prevent scrolling by touch.

Comment: What is the purpose of discarding the messages?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: The idea is to recognize certain gestures within the hook. The pointer messages should then not be processed by the application because they were already handled in the hook and should not result in scrolling or mouse movements in the application.

Comment: It has to work with unmodified third-party applications (hence the usage of a hook).

Comment: It seems to me that `WH_GETMESSAGE` is intended for monitoring and modification but not removal.  It seems that `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and `WH_MOUSE_LL` do allow removal with both showing this in the documentation: *it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window*

Comment: Removing DOES work with Keyboard Messages. Nevertheless, this sounds interesting. I will check whether a `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook receives `WM_POINTER...` messages. But even if doesn't, I might be able to filter the *resulting* mouse messages.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to work. `WM_POINTER...` messages don't reach the `WM_MOUSE_LL` hook. Also, filtering mouse events is not enough to prevent scrolling by touch.

Comment: if nothing helps, you could approach it with an api hook, either handwritten or using something like http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

Comment: @wonkorealtime: Thanks! I will consider this option (although it does sound kind of invasive ;).

Comment: C# has something called IMessageFilter which I think works exactly as you want. I wonder if there's a C++ equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

`WH_GETMESSAGE` is not designed to remove or modify messages, only to monitor them.  Unfortunately, mark's alternate solution - using `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and `WH_MOUSE_LL` - didn't appear to solve the problem either (because multitouch doesn't fall into the category of a mouse message).  Sorry, mark!

I'd like to point out `WH_CALLWNDPROC`, which receives messages *before* their intended window.  This seems to be the accepted way to modify messages.

Solution 2:

It's possible that the target window doesn't care about `WM_POINTER...` messages at all!  It could be detecting touch input through the [Raw Input](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/raw_input.html) API, like [this demo here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381673/Using-the-RawInput-API-to-Process-MultiTouch-Digit).  Try keeping an eye out for `WM_INPUT` messages as well.

Note 1: Raw Input messages can be removed, but cannot be modified or created.

Note 2: I'm not entirely sure, but unhandled `WM_INPUT` messages might create a memory leak because the thing is practically one massive pointer.  Just in case, handle the messages in your hook procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! However, I still had no success. Modifying or removing messages in `WH_CALLWNDPROC`does not work at all, not even for keyboard messages. Removing `WM_INPUT` messages does not prevent scrolling or clicking from touch. I start to believe that Windows handles "touch scrolling" on a very fundamental level...

Comment: @wmeyer may I ask on what application you are testing this?